# Multiple values from a SQL Database in php through to Java as separate variables

Tags: java, php, android, sql, json

I'm attempting to retrieve multiple values from a database through php to my android java in eclipse.
I'm managing to get all variations of json arrays except the one i need.

My database is:

```
**Aircraft**        **Status**
  A870_870              1
  A870_871              1
  A870_872              1
  A870_873              1 
  A870_874              1 
  A870_875              1
  A870_876              2
  A870_877              1
  A870_878              2
  A870_879              2 
  A870_880              2
  A870_881              0
  A870_882              0
  A870_883              0
  A870_884              0
  A870_885              0
```

The format I need so that my android app reads it is:

```
    {"A70_870":"1","A70_871":"1","A70_872":"1","A70_873":"1","A70_874":"1",
"A70_875":"1","A70_876":"2","A70_877":"1","A70_879":"2","A70_878":"2",
"A70_880":"2","A70_881":"0","A70_882":"0","A70_883":"0","A70_884":"0",
"A70_885":"0"}
```

I've been attempting different 'while' loops all sorts of other variations and manage to get all sorts of combinations except the one i need. Surely there is a way...?

My closest PHP attemp is below:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "mytestdatabase"); 

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
     echo 'Database connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
     exit(); 
     } 

$userdetails = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM aircraft_status"); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($userdetails) ;

$result_data = array(

    'A70_870'=>$row[1],
    'A70_871'=>$row[1],
    'A70_872'=>$row[1],
    'A70_873'=>$row[1],
    'A70_874'=>$row[1],
    'A70_875'=>$row[1],
    'A70_876'=>$row[1],
    'A70_877'=>$row[1],
    'A70_879'=>$row[1],
    'A70_878'=>$row[1],
    'A70_880'=>$row[1],
    'A70_881'=>$row[1],
    'A70_882'=>$row[1],
    'A70_883'=>$row[1],
    'A70_884'=>$row[1],
    'A70_885'=>$row[1],);

echo json_encode($result_data);
?>
```

It gives the correct format, but obviously only reads row 1. I can't access 3,5,7 etc..

If anyone can assist me in this it would be great!! :) I'm sure its something simple I'm not doing right....

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but is it not just wrapping result extraction in a while loop:

```
$userdetails = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM aircraft_status"); 

$result_data = array();

if ($userdetails) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userdetails)) {
    // $row[0] being aircraft and $row[1] being status
    array_push($result_data , $row[0], $row[1]);
  }

}
else {
  echo mysql_error();
}

echo json_encode($result_data);
```

My PHP is very rusty, so might need adjustments. Hope this gets you on the way.

Comment: Very Close, although it is the correct values, it is a 32 value array. I'm not sure of the terminology, but i need a {16:16} type of array. The results of your code was: ["A70_870","1","A70_871","1","A70_872","1","A70_873","1","A70_874","1","A70_875","1","A70_876","2","A70_877","1","A70_878","2","A70_879","2","A70_880","2","A70_881","0","A70_882","0","A70_883","0","A70_884","0","A70_885","0"]

Comment: Thanks to Lajos Veres;  $status[$rows['Aircraft']]= $rows['Status'];